# Animation when scrollbar appear

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, sass

I noticed the recent update on the Yarn website and observed that whenever there is an HTML element with 'overflow: auto', it has a really nice animation when the scrollbar appears—some kind of 'jumping' to its place.

In my web app, I have a div with 'overflow: auto', and I'd like to add this animation as well. Could you please assist me in achieving this?

You can see an example of the animation here: https://yarnpkg.com/package?name=d3. Click on the 'Versions' tab in the side menu, and you will see the scrollbar animation when it appears

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar-view">
  content of the div that can cause an overflow...
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  .sidebar-view {
    sidebar style....
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
  .sidebar-view::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
  }

  .sidebar-view::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #666;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }

  .sidebar-view::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background-color: #555;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the element with animation:

```
<ul class="menu__list" style="display: none; overflow: hidden; height: 0px; will-change: height; transition: height 1154ms ease-in-out 0s;">
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

We notice that when the height of the child element changes with the animation `ease-in-out`, the scrollbar changes as well.